# Having trouble getting ASP.NET URL rewrite to exclude a specific file

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all HTTP requests to my site to HTTPS except for the file "/blah.txt".  Here's the basic rewriting rule I've been trying.  I've tried to use {REQUEST_FILENAME} and {URL}.  I've tried several different patterns that I thought should match.

The rule below redirect **every** request to HTTPS **including** requests for blah.txt

```
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="blah\.txt$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Bryan for changing my direction of thought.  Sometimes I get stuck thinking that my solution will work based on bugless code.  In fact it appears that there is a bug in the rewriter that makes my first attempt at writing a rule fail.  However, this rule DOES work:

```
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Temp" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="blah\.txt$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Putting the matching rule in front of the other rule and causing it to stop processing of rules seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I only see one rule... that seems to match everything.  You need at least two rules here.

I'm not that familiar with IIS rewrite's feature.  So two questions:

Is there a "do nothing" action?

Won't any all-inclusive rule match ALL requests?  You probably need to put your blah.txt rule first.

Comment: I don't understand your point.  This rule has two conditions that must be met to be executed: HTTPS off and requested filename must not be "blah.txt".  If those are met, the rule runs.

The "do nothing action" is that there are no rules that would match if the filename was "blah.txt".

Comment: My mistake, I misread your rule.  However, my next step would be to try creating a second rule (put it first) that positively matches blah.txt and redirects to some test page.  Narrow down your problem.